# How can I cast string with offset after space into pyspark timestamp?

Tags: pyspark, casting, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["2003-01-01 02:00:00.0 -8:00"], 
    "string"
).toDF('ts')
df.collect()
[Row(ts='2003-01-01 02:00:00.0 -8:00')]
```

An I'm trying to make a timestamp type out of my ts but I just can't seem to make it work.
I tried many variants:

```
df = df.withColumn('cast', to_timestamp('ts', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S Z'))
df.collect()
[Row(ts='2003-01-01 02:00:00.0 -8:00', cast=None)]
```

```
df = df.withColumn('cast', to_timestamp('ts', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S X'))
df.collect()
[Row(ts='2003-01-01 02:00:00.0 -8:00', cast=None)]
```

```
df = df.withColumn('cast', to_timestamp('ts', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S x'))
df.collect()
[Row(ts='2003-01-01 02:00:00.0 -8:00', cast=None)]
```

```
df = df.withColumn('cast', to_timestamp('ts'))
df.collect()
[Row(ts='2003-01-01 02:00:00.0 -8:00', cast=None)]
```

But it does not work. It is frustrating especially since just removing the space before the offset works even without specifying the format..

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["2003-01-01 02:00:00.0-8:00"], 
    "string"
).toDF('ts')
df = df.withColumn('cast', to_timestamp('ts'))
df.collect()
[Row(ts='2003-01-01 02:00:00.0-8:00', cast=datetime.datetime(2003, 1, 1, 11, 0))]
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the space, if it works then?

Comment: this is not the format for x/z. It has to be -08:00, not -8:00

Comment: I guess I'll have to remove the space, but that's a additional step and this will be working on TBs of data so I wanted to see if it is possible without it.

Comment: I'm not sure how performant this will be, but you can use something like `df.withColumn("cast", from_utc_timestamp(to_utc_timestamp(df.ts, df.ts.substr(23, 5)), df.ts.substr(23, 5))).collect()`. According to it's plan, this transformation is applied during projecting so should be faster.

Comment: @Ondra, did you manage to solve the problem? Did you try my suggestion (see answer below)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ZZZZZ` instead of `Z`. Also works with `x` and `X`:

[Spark SQL manual says](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html):

> Five letters **outputs the hour and minute** and optional second, **with a colon**, such as `+01:30:15`.

Full text with other options explained:

> **One letter** outputs just the hour, such as `+01`, unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as `+0130`. **Two letters** outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as `+0130`. **Three letters** outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as `+01:30`. **Four letters** outputs the hour and minute and optional second, without a colon, such as `+013015`. **Five letters** outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as `+01:30:15`. **Six or more letters will fail**.

Spark SQL example:

```sql
SELECT to_timestamp('2003-01-01 02:00:00.1 -08:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S ZZZZZ')
```

returns

```
2003-01-01T10:00:00.100+0000
```